# Unknown Provider Error while trying to test generic angularjs $resource service

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, angularjs-service, angular-resource

I have generic service that create resources for my application:

```
(function(module) {
module.provider('restService', {

    resourceRegistry: {},
    addRestResource: function(entityName, entityProto) {
        this.resourceRegistry[entityName] = entityProto;
    },

    $get: function() {
        var restService;
        for (var entityName in this.resourceRegistry) {
            createRestResource(entityName, this.resourceRegistry[entityName]);
        };

        restService = {
            //createRestResource: createRestResource
        };

        return restService;
  }});

  function createRestResource(entityName, entityProto) {
    console.log('registering model: ' + entityName);
    module.provider(entityName, { $get: function($resource, $http) {
        var resource = $resource('/api/' + entityName + '/:id', { // TODO use config
            id : '@id' //this binds the ID of the model to the URL param
        },{
            query : { method : 'GET', isArray : true }, //this can also be called index or all
            update : { method : 'PUT' },
            create : { method : 'POST' },
            destroy : { method : 'DELETE' }
        });

        // here gose some other functionality unrelated to the topic...

        return resource;
    }});
}}(angular.module('restService', ['ngResource'])));
```

I can be used by any other module using

```
module.config(['restServiceProvider', function(restServiceProvider) {
  restServiceProvider.addRestResource('User', { name: null, email: null });
}
```

<s>And while above actually works for me in the application</s> Actually above neither works for me in the application (it was working due to some code left from before refactoring) nor I cannot get working jasmine/karma test for it. The problem is that trying various method to configure restServiceProvider I always end with error stating that for eg `TestEntity` there is unknown provider `TestEntityProider`. Although I have tried different approaches to configure the `resourceRegistry` before the resource is being created, here is some test file.

```
describe('testing restService', function () {
    var httpBackend;
    var theRestServiceProvider;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('ngResource');
        module('restService');
        var fakeModule = angular.module('test.app.config', ['ngResource'], function () {});
        fakeModule.config( function (restServiceProvider) {
            theRestServiceProvider = restServiceProvider;
            restServiceProvider.addRestResource('TestModel', {testProp: null});
        });

        module('test.app.config');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function ($httpBackend) {
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        })
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (restService) {}));



    describe('create restService entity', function() {
        it('should post entity with nonempty testProp',
            function() {
                theRestServiceProvider.addRestResource('TestModel', {testProp: null});

                inject(function(TestModel) {
                    var object = new TestModel();
                    object.testProp = 'John Doe';

                    httpBackend.expectPOST(/.*/,
                        function(postData) {
                            console.log("post data: " + postData);
                            jsonData = JSON.parse(postData);
                            expect(jsonData.testProp).toBe(object.testProp);

                            return jsonData;
                        }).respond({});

                    var response = object.$create();

                    httpBackend.flush();
                });
            });
    });
});
```

IMO this is because within the test the registering resource is being done 'too late' but still I don't know how to do this right.

**EDIT here is final resolution shortcut**:

```
(function(module) {
  module.provider('restService', function($provide) {
    var provider = {};
    // all the provider stuff goes here

    function createRestResource(entityName, entityProto) {
      /* 
       * using $provider here is fundamental here to properly create 
       * 'entityName' + Provider in the runtime instead of module initialisation
       * block
       */
       $provide.factory(entityName, function($resource, $http) { /* ... */ };
       // do other stuff...
    }

    return provider;
  }
}(angular.module('restServiceModule', ['ngResource'])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made very similar thing here https://github.com/tunguski/matsuo-ng-resource/blob/master/matsuo-ng-resource.js, maybe it will help you.

Basically I'm adding new resource providers to `$provide` not to `module`. It works. I think it's main difference.

Comment: you're right. using $provide is enough to solve my problem as it allows to register $resource providers at runtime. I will correct my code to show exact solution. Hope it will help others because it was not that easy to figure out for me even if the fix is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with karma/jasmine but BDD syntax seems to be similar.
In my understanding you should have something like this

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('restService');
    inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _restService_, _ngResource_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        restService = _restService_;
        ngResource = _ngResource_;
    })
});
```

instead of all you `beforeEach`. Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject).
If you want to provide mocks instead of injected services you would use

```
    module('restService', function($provide){
        $provide.value('serviceToMock', mockObject);
    });
```

Note that naming module and provider/service/factory with same name may be confusing at later stage...